# How do I Duplicate a rigged character (armature)?

Tags: armature, linked-data, library, library-overrides

How do I get multiple instances of a rigged character (that I have downloaded) in my project and be able to pose them individually?

All I have got working is linking the rigged character (from the original .blend file) and creating a proxy. This only works for one instance per original .blend file of a rigged character. How do I duplicate this character and pose the copies individually.

The only solution I have found is to create a new blend file for every character and then linking them all. This will not work for me because I will set up about 30 scenes, with multiple characters in each scene.

Comment: Welcome to our Stack Exchange Yogsther.   Can you state your question as a question, to help narrow in on what kind of answers you want?

Comment: @jwrush I have rephrased my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to do with library overrides.  First, you have to prepare the library file properly. But that's simple.  Select the armature and the mesh and stick them both in the same collection.

Next, you have to repeat these steps for each individual copy you want in a destination file:

1. Link the *collection* from the source file using File -> Link
2. *Immediately* Create a *Library override* using Object -> Relations -> Make Library Override

This will result in any number of copies of the original collection.  The first will have the original collection's name, but the rest will follow the naming convention for duplicate names (name.NNN).  Unfortunately in 2.93 you can't change the names.

Once you've don this you can select any of the the individual armatures, place them in pose mode, and independently pose them.